# getAttribute() and setAttribute() not working

Tags: jquery, html

For some reason my function for loading images isn't working.

I have many popups on a page which show on hover. Some have one image others have a few. Now this is slowing the loading times down so I don't want to load the image until the user hovers.

To do this I am basically creating a loop which grabs each image and changes the `src` attribute to the value of the `data-src` attribute.

**Here's my code:**

```js
 jQuery('.tool_tip').hover(
            function(){
                var pop_class = jQuery(this).data("tool");
                var tool_pop = jQuery("#" + pop_class);
                tool_pop.addClass('tool_open');

                tool_pop.find('img').each(function(){
                    var current = jQuery(this);
                    if(!current.hasClass('loaded')){
                        current.setAttribute('src', current.getAttribute('data-src'));
                        current.addClass('loaded'); 
                    }else{
                        return;
                    }
                });
            }, function(){
                var pop_class = jQuery(this).data("tool");
                jQuery("#" + pop_class).removeClass('tool_open');
            }
        );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <h2>Delivery Type <img class="tool_tip" data-tool="delivery_pop" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/tool_tip.png" alt="tool tip"></h2>

<div id="delivery_pop" class="tool_pop">
  <div class="flex_pop">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/lazy_image.svg" data-src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/delivery.jpeg" alt="Angle Image">
    <p>You or your courier can collect from our offices any weekday between 8am and 5pm</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why vote to close? If I have done something wrong tell me and I will correct it. Just looking for some help

Comment: There should be errors in the console because of `setAttribute` and `getAttribute`. And wrapping a jQuery object in a jQuery object is useless.

Comment: Ok thanks. "And wrapping a jQuery object in a jQuery object is useless" could you explain this please?

Comment: Can you please show your HTML and what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Probably means `var tool_pop = jQuery("#" + pop_class);
            jQuery(tool_pop).addClass('tool_open');` - tool_pop is already a jQuery object (from the first line). You don't need to wrap it inside another one. Just call addClass on it directly.

Comment: The same for `jQuery(current)`. `current` is already a jQuery object (`var current = jQuery(this);`).

Comment: Why would you explicitly need 'this' anyway? If you are looking to get hold of the object within the loop, you could easily define that as parameters to your delegate. Take a look at the API documentation - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: I will update my code to show exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: "If I have done something wrong tell me and I will correct it"...you need to include actual error messages and/or descriptions of unexpected / incorrect behaviour. "isn't working" or "won't run" is not an adequate description to allow anyone to easily understand the problem. Besides, a programmer should be able to do at least basic debugging - "not working" is what the users say when they didn't press the "on" button :-). A close vote can be given for questions which don't give enough details to allow someone to reproduce the issue. I didn't vote but that would be the logic, I should think.

Comment: [Without code, users will have to guess what might be wrong.... if the code is full of compile errors or artificial bugs caused by translation to the question, these may hide the actual problem.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong functions to get/set the attributes. With a jQuery object you should use use .attr or .data not getAttribute() and setAttribute()

```
jQuery('.tool_tip').hover(
    function(){
        var pop_class = jQuery(this).data("tool");
        var tool_pop = jQuery("#" + pop_class);
        tool_pop.addClass('tool_open');

        tool_pop.find('img').each(function(){
            var current = jQuery(this);
            if(!current.hasClass('loaded')){
                current.attr('src', current.attr('data-src'));
                current.addClass('loaded'); 
            }else{
                return;
            }
        });
    }, function(){
        var pop_class = jQuery(this).data("tool");
        jQuery("#" + pop_class).removeClass('tool_open');
    }
);
```

Comment: To use setAttribute, you would have had to do `current[0].setAttribute()` to access the underlying element. However using .attr() is the correct way.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
           tool_pop.find('img').each(function(elem){
                var current = jQuery(elem);
                if(!current.hasClass('loaded')){
                    current.setAttribute('src', current.getAttribute('data-src'));
                    current.addClass('loaded'); 
                }else{
                    return;
                }
```

Comment: What have you changed and why?

Comment: You obviously didn't read the comment that setAttribute() doesn't exist in jQuery. it should be .attr().